# Quicksorting a string array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, quicksort

Complete Java newbie so please forgive any silly mistakes. I'm working on a larger assignment but have gotten stuck on a quicksort method and despite playing with it for the last few hours and looking at it til I've almost gone blind, I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

I'm getting an error message "error: method QuicksortString in class testmenu01 cannot be applied to given types". I know that this is something to do with how I've passed parameters in, but have tried and retried and cannot find my mistake. I'm sure its something silly and glaringly obvious, but cannot find it. Would really appreciate any help, thanks!

```
public class testmenu01 {

public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] nameArr = {"Anna", "Brad", "Charles", "Debbie", "Emma", "Fergal"};
    QuicksortString( nameArr );


}

public void QuicksortString(String [] stringArray, int start, int end) {
    int i = start;
    int k = end;
    if (end - start >= 1) {
        String pivot = stringArray[start];
        while (k > i) {
            while (stringArray[i].compareTo(pivot) <= 0 && i <= end && k > i)
                i++;
            while (stringArray[k].compareTo(pivot) > 0 && k >= start && k >= i)
                k--;
            if (k > i)
                swap(stringArray, i, k);
        }
        swap(stringArray, start, k);
        QuicksortString(stringArray, start, k - 1);
        QuicksortString(stringArray, k + 1, end);
    } else { return; }
}
public void swap(String array[], int index1, int index2) {
    String temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;
}
```

}

Comment: the `QuicksortString` method says "give me three arguments"  the first being the string array, the second being the start (`int`) and the third being the end(`int`). you've only passed the string array so far. Also, it has to be `static` to be called in the `main` method otherwise you'll need to create an instance and then call the method upon that.

Comment: By the way, make sure you comply with the standard Java naming conventions: method names have to start with a lowercase letter. Names starting in uppercase should be used for types (classes, interfaces, enums) only.

Comment: Some good tips in the comments. Another tip: it can be helpful to use an IDE/editor with (for example) syntax highlighting. This sort of errors will normally be flagged clearly.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, changing `QuicksortString( nameArr );` in the main method into `QuicksortString( nameArr, 0,nameArr.length-1 );` since you defined this method with  a parameter list of three parameters:`public void QuicksortString(String [] stringArray, int start, int end)`. Just like your recursive call.

Besides, you'd better change to another line for the `return` in the `else`clause:

```
else { 
    return; 
}
```

And it should be a `static` method for both `swap` and `QuicksortString`(`quicksortString`is a better method name in java) to let the `static` method `main` call them without instantiating the class.